# Unterschied zwischen “xxxx, in + dem/der/den” und “xxxxx, worin” beim Nebensatz

Tags: preposition, subordinate-clause

Bsp.:

> Im Versuch wurde eine Messung durchgeführt, worin das Gewicht gemessen
>   wurde.

und

> Im Versuch wurde eine Messung durchgeführt, in der das Gewicht gemessen
>   wurde.

Which one is right? or we can use both of them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are referring back to a particular noun in the first part of the sentence you should use the preposition with the relevant part of 'der', so:

> Im Versuch wurde eine Messung durchgeführt, in der das Gewicht gemessen wurde.

Worin can is primarily used to refer back to a whole clause

Worin (and generally wo- constructions) are also used to refer back to neuter indefinites (words like alles, etwas, manches, nichts) or after a neuter adjective referring to something indefinite.

Comment: I would consider *bei der* instead of *in der* even better.